# android background repeat-y

Tags: android, background, gravity

I have an image that I want to position in the right and repeat it on y axis.
Something like "background: url(img.png) right repeat-y" in HTML.

Is it possible to do this in android?

When I set this bitmap as a background it's not in the right:

```
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:src="@drawable/img_list"
  android:filter="true"
  android:dither="true"
  android:tileMode="repeat"
  android:gravity="right" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the following code for repeating a image on y axis as background:

```
 <bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:src="@drawable/background"
        android:tileMode="repeat"
        android:antialias="true"
        android:dither="false"
        android:filter="false"
        android:gravity="left"
    />
```

For seperate TileModes for X and Y u need to do this in code:

```
    BitmapDrawable TileMe = new BitmapDrawable(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.listbackground));
      //TileMe.setTileModeX(TileMode.REPEAT);
      TileMe.setTileModeY(TileMode.REPEAT);
```

Comment: ok, but I want to set background to right edge, but when I set tileMode to repeat, gravity attribute is ignored and set to left

Comment: a now i get it, i tryed some stuff out but didnt find the solution yet.. I think there must be some way to set tilemode seperate for x and y but havent found it yet..Need to go now so hopefully someone else will answer your question soon.

Comment: I think u found the answer already, but i've updated my answer with a working anwer.. It only possible to set seperate TileMode in code..

Comment: BitmapDrawable is deprecated, any alternatives?

Comment: Only the constructor is deprecated, you can use: BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable  = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.tile_image));